# objective-c textfield user leaves textfield

Tags: objective-c, textfield

I have two custom textfields, one needs to validate for currency, the other for a percentage input. I'm running into this weird situation where if I click in the first field, do nothing, then click in the second text field, the first one gets populated with NaN - which is because I am trying to format nothing.

How can I detect a user doing this? I tried

```
if (textField.text != nil || ![textField.text isEqualToString:@""] || textField.text != NULL) {
```

but that didn't trap it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can probably hack it in the textFieldDidEndEditing() method and say if textField.text.length == 0, textField.text = @"";

Comment: So you tried checking for `nil` or empty strings and it isn't working. When you step through it in the debugger, what is the value of `textField.text` that causes the problem?

Comment: `nil == NULL` (for the pedants, `nil = (id) 0`, `NULL = (void*) 0`). So checking against both is always a waste of time.

Comment: First off, thanks for the responses, I had to step out to a meeting. I am checking the value in the textFieldDidEndEditing.

Comment: My test for a non-nil non-empty string is simply `[textField.text length] > 0`. As a test, add `NSLog(@"text: '%@'; length: %ud", textField.text, [textField.text length])` to see what the string actually is.